# Non-Linear Iteration in R with ln() function

Tags: r, statistics, iteration, time-series, non-linear-regression

I am very new to R and I would like to ask how to perform an iteration of a time series data using the formula below:

ln(x) + x =  constant,

where x is the data taken from the time series. The limits of x is from zero to infinity, as long as the left hand side will be equivalent to the right hand side. I would also like to ask how to show the calculated x values to predict future event, say if I have a data from 2013 to 2014 then I want to predict the values on 2015. The frequency of the data is exactly from January to December (frequency=12).

Comment: There is no `ln()` function in base R. If you're using additional packages, please be explicit about which ones are involved. Also, it helps to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question with sample input and desired output.

Comment: I believe the OP meant the natural logarithm of `x` by using "ln(x)". I agree with MrFlick, however, that a reproducible example would be very helpful.

Comment: You want to apply a formula on each element of your time serie but what you wrote is an equation involving one parameter. Please reword your problem!